# How to combine two select SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
  Select 
      b.subCusNo, c.companyName as [Subsidiary], b.equityInterest,b.relation
  From  
      cusparentsub b, customerdetails c
  Where 
      b.subcusNo = c.custNo 

  Select  
      b.parentCusNo,c.companyName as [Parent Company], b.equityInterest, b.relation
  From 
      cusparentsub b, customerdetails c
  Where 
      b.parentcusNo = c.custNo
```

Above are two SQL statements. Is it possible to join the select statement and the output will be in a table with `subcusno, companyname, parentcusno, companyname, equityinterest` and relation data?

I want the `companyname` column to appear after `subcusno` column and after `parentcusno`. Both of the company name data is from the same table. Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: You can use a union statement

Comment: i tried , it did not show any data.

Comment: Ugh, that ugly obsolete A,B join syntax :(

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @mir, please, add sample source data to your question and describe desired output.

Comment: A `UNION` not returning any data, that means none of its selects returns any data...

Comment: I already got the right query for the question. :)

Comment: Too bad, I'm sure the one I was currently writing was exectly what you wanted.

Comment: if you don't mind , you can share it here. Maybe I can learn the new query for the question :)

Comment: @mir, Please provide proper data and desire output. what is relationship between `company` and `sub company` in table. how it is define.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a more recent JOIN syntax. I use left join for the parent, but depends on what you really want, you can use the INNER JOIN

```
SELECT b.subCusNo,
       c.companyName,
       b.parentCusNo,
       pc.companyName AS [Parent Company],
       b.equityInterest,
       b.relation
FROM cusparentsub b
JOIN customerdetails c ON b.subcusNo = c.custNo
LEFT JOIN customerdetails pc ON b.parentCusNo=pc.subCusNo
```

Comment: -- on the last row *pc.subcusNo changed to pc.custNo and it work perfectly.   thank you so much :)

Comment: @mir "did not work" is not an error message. Elaborate what is the right result and what is wrong with result provided by this query.

Comment: this is the right query that I need :) http://stackoverflow.com/users/5921826/ivan-starostin

Comment: @Mir,post your sample data and expected result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.subCusNo, b.parentCusNo,c.companyName as [Subsidiary],   
b.equityInterest,b.relation
FROM cusparentsub b
JOIN customerdetails c ON b.subcusNo = c.custNo 
JOIN customerdetails d ON b.parentcusNo = d.custNo
```

Comment: @mir "did not work" is not an error message. Elaborate what is the right result and what is wrong with result provided by this query.

Comment: I already got the right query. For this query,it  only shows one column of company name, while I need two columns of company name. the query is working , but it did not show the result that i need

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cd.custNo, --What you want to see
,ISNULL(c1.subcusNo,c2.parentcusNo) AS Matched_Customer_No
FROM customerdetails cd
    LEFT JOIN cusparentsub c1
        ON c1.subcusNo = cd.custNo
    LEFT JOIN cusparentsub c2
        ON c2.parentcusNo = cd.custNo
```

Comment: thank you for answering :), but it did not working .

Comment: @mir "did not work" is not an error message. Elaborate what is the right result and what is wrong with result provided by this query.

Comment: I already got the right query. For this query ,it combines the data both from subcusno and parentcusno. I need them in separate column. the query is working , but it did not show the result that i need

Comment: Because we do not know the table structures, it is difficult to encode the correct association.
Can you try the following?